# How to size text based on the height of page?

Tags: css

I want a single form of my website to follow a simple rule: the page must appear identical at every resolution you watch.

So I need `h1` be height, e.g., 10% of page, `h2` be 7%, etc..

Is there a way to realize this with CSS?

Comment: @AmitJoki: thanks, but...can you do some example?

Comment: just search for it... in google.

Comment: sad. ..sad.. sad... Isn't this site here for these ?!

Comment: To get text to the same height on every resolution they would all have to be the same font size. Because each font size has a different line height. Could you provide some code example of what you are working with? And what you currently have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as a pure CSS solution you could use `vh` [Viewport-percentage](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-values/#viewport-relative-lengths) lengths for elements to specify their `font-size`/`line-height` base on the viewport height:

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/6ahf8/)**

```css
h1 { font-size: 10vh; line-height: 10vh; }
h2 { font-size: 7vh;  line-height: 7vh; }
```

> **[5.1.2 Viewport-percentage lengths: the vw, vh, vmin, vmax units](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-values/#viewport-relative-lengths)**
>
> The viewport-percentage lengths are relative to the size of the
>   initial containing block. When the height or width of the initial
>   containing block is changed, they are scaled accordingly. However,
>   when the value of overflow on the root element is auto, any scroll
>   bars are assumed not to exist. Note that the initial containing
>   block’s size is affected by the presence of scrollbars on the
>   viewport.
>
> **[vh unit](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-values/#vh)**
>   Equal to 1% of the height of the initial containing block.

It's worth noting that `vh` unit [is supported in the modern web browsers](http://caniuse.com/viewport-units) (including IE9+).